# CSS Two Columns in row in responsive

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have two row inside a row contains 3 `li` I want to make in reponsive 2 `li`
but it's dosn't worrk
PS : ITS FOR EMAIL HTML

**demo**

http://jsbin.com/fobejarexi/3/edit?html,css,output

So the result should look like this on small screens.

```
image   image

image   image

image   image
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the table from your layout for a start...

Comment: @Stuart i use table for email html

Comment: I see, then it will be tricky to transform the 3 columns into 2 columns on small screens....

Comment: @Stuart  into 2 columns on reponsive can u make example for that ?

Comment: I could, but it would be far more beneficial for you to learn yourself.

Here are some great resources:

- http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

As the comments note, **you need `<table>`s** instead of `<li>`'s if this is for an HTML email. I've included some code below that achieves what you ask.

One caveat: **For simplicity purposes, this only works in mobile email clients that support `@media` queries.** So this work in iOS Mail, but not mobile Gmail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .table {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 600px;" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=1"></td>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=2"></td>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=3"></td>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=4"></td>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=5"></td>
      <td style="display: block; float: left; line-height: 0;" class="td"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=6"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I add switch a three column in desktop to a two column in mobile - and making sure it works in GMail? I've tried hiding the third item inline and in media qiueries bring it back when someone is on a desktop device - still dose not work...

Comment: That's tough, but possible. Gmail doesn't support media queries, so they can't be used. [Fabio Carniero's 3 Column Scaffold](https://github.com/fcarneiro/tedc15_template/blob/master/scaffolds/3_column_scaffold_centering.html) achieves what you ask, even in Gmail (on mobile, the third column will drop below the other two).

Comment: Great! But I was asking about hiding the right column... in gmail - it's really unfortunate that gmail is not supporting mqs

Comment: Yea, in Gmail there's currently no way to show something on wide and hide it on narrow. You can only move it around.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up snippet of code I use to shift 2 rows of 3 to 3 rows of 2 on mobile, which works across all platforms, even if they don't support media queries:

```
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 94%; max-width: 615px;">
                <tr><td style="text-align: center; font-size: 0; padding: 15px 0 0px 0;">
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr><td width="200" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;" class="wrapper2">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if  (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr><td width="200" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;" class="wrapper2">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;" class="wrapper2">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 50%; max-width: 205px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="188" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width: 92%;" class="wrapper2">
                                <tr><td align="center">
                                        <img alt="" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/188x220" style="border: 0; display: block;" class="gridimg" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if  (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <![endif]-->
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

You will want to enhance this with some classes to help it look better on iPhones and older Androids, but it will look okay on the Gmail app.